# doesn't it need to delete thread object?

Tags: c#

i have a search thread in my project . 
the thread is created in 'Form1()' function:

```
objSearchThread = new Thread(this.Thread_Func);
```

when user clicks the 'search' button, Start() function is called:

```
private void Button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objSearchThread.Start();
}
```

second clicked of this button, crashed! because the thread is 'Started' state.
if i change my button clicked code, and i add 'new' command. it works without error or crashing:

```
private void Button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objSearchThread = new Thread(this.Thread_Func);
    objSearchThread.Start();
}
```

doesn't it need to delete thread object(objSearchThread )?
does it need to call Abort() or other functions, when thread working ends?
is second code that i write here correct?

Comment: Instance of `Thread`represents state / info about one, single thread. You can start one thread only once, so that is way you are getting error. Calling twice `Start` tries to run twice the same thread.. When using `new` you create new instance of `Thread` that represent another thread. But in this case you loose info about previous (you won't abe able to determine wheter thread is completed or start it again when completed)

Comment: Your second solution is correct. However, it's not very efficient. Look into tasks, and use `Task.Run(this.Thread_Func)`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx Consider using `await` and `async` to make it easy to update your UI after searching is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to do anything. The thread will just finish when it has no more work to do. You might want to consider scheduling it to execute on the thread pool however, instead of creating a new thread each time. You could do that directly, or via the Task Parallel Libray (TPL) with the `Task` API. Alternatively, you might want to use `BackgroundWorker`, as that makes it easier to report progress to the UI. (Depending on what you're doing, you may not even need another thread at all - if you're calling a web service for example, you may be able to use the async facilities in C# 5 to make the code simpler *and* more efficient in one go...)

If you're using `Thread` directly, however, you *do* need to create a new `Thread` object each time you want to start it, as you can't reuse a thread.

Additionally, unless you *need* this to be an instance variable, you should consider making it a local variable. When do you ever access the thread other than in method?

Comment: Even easier than using a `BackgroundWorker` is using `async` and `await` in combination with `Task.Run(Action)` (assuming a thread is actually needed for CPU intensive work, when it's not just IO).

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: Possibly - it depends on the situation. But I've included async in the answer now anyway :)